# About the logarithm of the negative unit

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

$${e}^{iz} = \cos(z)+i\sin(z)$$
and
$$e^{i\pi}=-1$$
But then
$$\ln(-1)$$
can be infinite many numbers (positive and negative), as $z$ is the natural logarithm of that number and the solution to the initial equation. My doubt: Is
$$\ln(-1) = \pm (2k-1)i\pi$$
where $k$ is an integer, true? Is correct saying $\ln(-1)$ is, for example, equal to $-3i\pi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logarithm can just be chosen branchwise. That means that you have to fix one $k$. Of course it will not extend to a continuous function on $\mathbb{C} -0$ exactly because running around $0$ one time adds an imaginary angle.

In particular the complex $e^{z}$ has no inverse, for all $z \in \mathbb{C}-0$.

Answer (score 1):

The logarithm is what is known as a "multivalued function" in complex analysis.  That is, $\log(z)$ is not just one complex number, it is the set of all $w$ such that $e^w = z$.  If $w_0$ is one of these, then these are $w_0 + 2 \pi i n$ for all integers $n$.  For many purposes we would like to single out one particular choice: a "branch" of the logarithm function.  A popular choice (the "principal branch", often denoted as $\text{Log} (z)$), is given by $\text{Log}(r e^{i\theta}) = \ln(r) + i \theta$ for $r > 0$ and $-\pi < \theta \le \pi$.  So $\text{Log}(-1) = i \pi$, but all other odd integer multiples of $i \pi$ are also values of $\log(-1)$.